# Marshall signals history

Tags: safety, airport

When were airport marhall signals used for the first time? What is the history of these signals? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean history of civil aviation marshaling or aviation including military airfields?

Comment: I mean only history of civil aviation

Comment: The standard marshaling signs have been introduced in 1956 in ICAO Rules of the Air to have an international language, but someone has to explain how they were agreed, and where they were used first. Or if you are only interested in the ICAO story, let me know, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Im courious about their use for the first time, and history of these signals, who  invented this system....some information about that if u have.....thank you again!